# Is it a good and safe way using session to store site configuration?

Tags: php, session

I'm using PHP and MySQL. There are some site configuration variables that I need on every page, such as site_url, site_path, contact_email, default_timezone...etc.

Instead of retrieving these values from database on every page refresh, I stored them in session on the first page visit.

I'v been using this way for a while, and I haven't encountered any problems. The only disadvantage I see now is if a value if changed, I have to close browser to clear session and then reload. (but these values are pretty much static)

I'm wondering if this is ok. Is this gonna cause any other problems?

And, how much info can I store in session? Is there a limit?

Answer (score 1):

Some of those sound like they're global values, common to all users. That's a poor candidate for a session value. It'd be better to store those in a file somewhere. There's no point in storing "site_url" for 50,000 sessions, if it's the same value for each of them. Waste of time and space.

Session storage should be execlusively for per-user data, things which aren't/can't be shared between multiple users.

There's no practical limit to session storage, other than how much disk space you have, PHP's memory_limit, and how much cpu time you're willing to waste parseing multi-megabytes of data for every hit on your site.

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit in how much you can store in a session but there's a limit of how much memory php can use http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: The limist is also imposed by disk space quota in webserver's `temp` directory (if using default session handlers) or for example by size of database field (if using custom session handlers which store session data in database)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many users you expect. In anything more than a few dozens at a time, storing this information in session data isn't a good idea.

The session shouldn't really act as a cache in this case. The issue is that if you have 10 thousand sessions, then the session data has to be duplicated 10 thousand times. This isn't efficient.

If your project size warrants it, you'd be better off using something like memcached (or APC cache) to store the cached values for a given period of time. If you're using a database class to handle the config, have the DB class fetch from the cache for you so all places that call the code can do it without worrying about the implementation. You can try to use files as a cache mechanism, but you'll have to worry about cache time outs and file access in that case. Measure before making a decision.